# How to iterate through getResultList in openJpa. List returning does not have Entity. fetching data has customized fields

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I am getting results by running native query in Openjpa.

```
    .... reportQueryInstance =...createNativeQuery(QueryString,Object.class);
    List<Object> Listtemp = reportQueryInstance.getResultList();

for(Object obj:wubfaListtemp){

                    }
```

how can i loop through the result i get. which contains 5 columns for which i don't have entity and i can't.I know how to loop if result is list of entity.

ex:

```
date:   shift:   arr-dep:    arr:    dep:
value   value1  value2    value3  value4
```

Comment: You mean you get a `List<Object[]>` returned as per the JPA spec?

Comment: i gave some example right i will get such data when i execute the sql query as is in db console. since i didn't have any entity i assigned the result to a List<Object>. am i supposed to assign to List<Object[]>?

Comment: If you have a query that returns multiple columns then your result will be of type `List<Object[]>` as I already said. That is in the JPA spec. Why not try it?

Comment: its not working.its only giving me column one data.  while looping i sent object to this below method....
private String resultAsString(Object o) {
     if (o instanceof Object[]) {
         return Arrays.asList((Object[])o).toString();
     } else {
         return String.valueOf(o);
     }
 }

Comment: so post your query and everything else. All anyone can tell you is what the JPA spec says.

Comment: actually after some improving my code List<Object[]> worked and i should not send Object.class while calling createNativeQuery.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i =0; i<Listtemp.size(); i++) {
           Object=Listtemp.get(i);
           Object.get(date);

 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.